# Vb.net - How to prevent multiple user to execute one function before it actually finishes last execution

Tags: vb.net

I have a Vb.Net function to submit details to database, suppose i want to prevent multiple user to proceed the function at the same time. the second person could get the chance to execute the function only after the first person get rid out from that function.

Comment: Database locking is quite a broad topic. You might find inspirations is articles like [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/6-ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt).

Comment: Odds are you don't need to prevent this in the first. What reason do you need this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You may setup optimistic concurrency. The idea is to have RowVersion column which automatically increases it's value when the row is modified. When someone wants to update the row it specifies extra condition in `WHERE`, that RowVersion must match the known RowVersion (which was retrieved before). If multiple users try to update the same row, only one can succeed. The others will miss and you can display warning message for them.

In MSSQL there is a `timestamp` type for such cases.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create thread-safe queue where all user will add their arguments and background process will execute functions with given arguments one by one. Which this approach you will not depend on the type or version of database.

You can use [ConcurrentQueue(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) for implementation

```vb
Public Class DetailsRepository

    Private ReadOnly _queue As ConcurrentQueue(Of Object)
    Private _cancellationSource As CancellationTokenSource
    Private _cancellationToken As CancellationToken
    Private _task As Task

    Public Sub New()
        _queue = New ConcurrentQueue(Of Object)()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Submit(arguments As Object)
        queue.Enqueue(arguments);
    End Sub

    Public Sub Start()
        _cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource()
        _cancellationToken = _cancellationSource.Token
        _task = Task.Run(AddressOf ExecuteSubmits, _cancellationToken)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Stop()
        _cancellationSource.Cancel()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExecuteSubmits()
        While True
            Dim argument As Object
            If _queue.TryDequeue(argument) Then
                ' Execute database query with provided arguments
            End If
            If _cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested Then
                Exit While
            End If
        End
    End Sub
End Class
```

Create singleton instance of this class in the entry point of you application and use it every where you need execute that function